# dropping "s" on third person singular

Tags: verbs

The sentence is:
It is important that he learn French. What is the rule or guideline that says to drop the "s"? I am tutoring a non-native English speaker.

Comment: If you're referring to the verb "learn", it's not a simple present tense situation.  I forget what it's called this week, but the use of the verb is in a prospective/future sense.

Comment: The third person singular subjunctive is one of the only remaining uses  in modern English of the subjunctive mood that is distinguishable as a separate inflection. This article explains it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive